# What is the difference between 7 dBi and 10 dBi WiFi router antenna for 5.8 GHz?

Tags: antenna

5.8 GHz known as short range but higher speed for WLAN comm such as for WiFi routers. What would be advantages of using 10 dBi router antenna instead of 7 dBi at 5.8 GHz? Longer distance?

Comment: Twice the radiated power on the face of it.

Comment: @Andyaka assuming it's directional antenna and gain enhancement happens thanks to directivity increment

Comment: He means ERP, effective radiated power.  You're correct that the total radiated power stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

The 10dBi antenna will increase the range by about 1.4X in free space, provided the antennas are polarized and aligned correctly.  The 7dBi will be more forgiving of misalignments.  For a typical WiFi setup, where portable users are generally unaware of their antenna location or orientation, and in some cases even the router's location, I'd choose the 7dBi for its wider angle.

Comment: That assumes the antenna patterns are fixed.  If it's a MIMO setup, then the beam pattern and directivity are dynamically adjustable, within constraints, of course.

Comment: Let me ask a question then, how big change would happen in distance and coverage if I use 1 dBi omnidirectional   instead of 5 dBi omni?

Comment: Your range would drop to about 0.65 the range of a carefully aligned device compared to the 5dBi, but would be better for devices off the plane normal to the antenna.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis excuse me which devices you mean? like cell phones?

Comment: Exactly.  Laptops as well.